# How to use Rest API to connect React Native app and Prestshop 1.7?

Tags: react-native, prestashop-1.7, rest

I'm planning to build a mobile app in React Native, I'm familiar with Prestashop 1.7. I need to know, how to connect React Native and Prestashop 1.7 using Rest API?

Kindly, tell me how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Axios** library, pretty straightforward, easy to use and less verbose than the Fetch API.

Here's their official docs website: https://axios-http.com/

And their Github repository: https://github.com/axios/axios